# How to import ESRI grid into Matlab

Tags: arcgis-desktop, matlab, esri-grid-format

I have some ESRI grid data that I would like to import into Matlab. 
As a typical ESRI grid data I have the two folders with the *.adf files and *.dat, *.nit and*.dat files.

I would like to know how can I import the information stored in those files into Matlab.

Tank you all!

Answer (score 3):

I would convert the GRID to ASCII format first using [Raster to ASCII (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000005000000).  If you have many GRIDs, use the batch conversion by right-clicking on the tool and selecting "batch".  Then you can easily bring in the ASCII files into MATLAB using `arcgridread`.  Here's an example from [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/arcgridread.html):

```
[Z,R] = arcgridread('MtWashington-ft.grd');
mapshow(Z,R,'DisplayType','surface');
xlabel('x (easting in meters)'); ylabel('y (northing in meters)')
demcmap(Z)
```

There is also a discussion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/23995/8104) that may give you some ideas too.

Another option is to convert your ESRI grids to another format, such as a TIFF, and bring them into MATLAB using `imread` ([source](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have already tried that but it's not working. When I convert it to ASCII I only get like the 'mask' of my data , that is: -9999 and 2 indicating whether there is a value or no data but not the actual value at each given point. Any idea how to retrieve the value?